# webview loaddata in android does not load a picture from img src

Tags: android, webview, image, src

I use loadData method to load some html content into a webview, but when it encounters something like this :
    `<a href="http://www.anywebsite.fr/">some text</a><img src="http://www.anotherwebsite.fr/thewantedpicture" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" />`
I only get this in the application :
[some text](http://www.anywebsite.fr/)
And if I'm not mistaken, this should also display the picture ?
If someone has any lead, thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for the `loadData()` method](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) you'll see it says:

> Content loaded through this mechanism does not have the ability to load content from the network.

Try using [the `loadDataWithBaseURL()` method](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) instead.

Comment: oh great, slip out of my mind this one. I remember reading this a long time ago lol...
thanks

Comment: Actually, it works as fine as the loadData() but still no picture displayed... I don't understand why...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just need to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to your App Manifest.