# android how to create a try it yourself editor

Tags: android

I have read about javascript editors here, more specifically refered this link [How to create a JavaScript "Try It Yourself" Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794998/how-to-create-a-javascript-try-it-yourself-editor) but I would want to know how to integrate a java script into my android app? Is the thing about having a JavaScript in the core and having an Android try it yourself editor the right way? I am really confused :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put WebView on your scene and load data to it dynamically

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950729/rendering-html-in-a-webview-with-custom-css) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906258/webview-loaddata-in-android-does-not-load-a-picture-from-img-src)

Comment: :Thank you...Was having a thought about that but youve helped me with the links