# How to change WebView content on Button click in Android?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am implementing a small project in which I'm diplaying a local image in my webview (in order to use the Zooming & Panning functionality), and on a button click the Next Image will be loaded.
I'm able to load the image, but on the Button click I'm unable to reload the webview with the new image.

Any suggestions will really helpful. :)

Below is my WebViewActivity.java code:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.web_view_activity);

    // Initialize all View Components

    flippy = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
    WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    next = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.next);
    next.setAlpha(100);
    previous = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.previous);
    previous.setAlpha(100);


    mWebView.setInitialScale(0);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);


    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/start.png");
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);



}

public void onClickFeature (View v)
{
    int id = v.getId ();
    switch (id) {
    case R.id.next :    
            imagename = /*nextImagename*/;
           mWebView.loadUrl(imagename)
               flippy.showNext();
            break;

    case R.id.previous:
            imagename = /*previousImagename*/;
    mWebView.loadUrl(imagename)
        flippy.showNext();
    break;
    default:
    break;
}
}
```

Following is the web_view_activity.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ViewFlipper
         android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</ViewFlipper>


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/previous"
        android:layout_width="59dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="onClickFeature"
        android:src="@drawable/previous" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="59dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|right"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="onClickFeature"
        android:src="@drawable/next" />
```

Comment: Can you post some code...and make a comment where is not working or not doing what you want to do.

Comment: Code would help to solve your problem...

Comment: I have used Viewflipper to update change the webview.

Answer (score 1):

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
 public void onClick(View v) {
    WebViewActivity.this.mWebView.loadUrl("your url array");
 }
});
```

You need to handle the url array increment and decrements manually.

Answer (score 0):

This question can help you problem:
[android how to create a try it yourself editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644156/android-how-to-create-a-try-it-yourself-editor/11644543#11644543)

You can dynamicly prepare and upload data to your WebView (or set url from net)